# Editing a model plus a list of it's child elements on one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Okay so I have a Product entity which has one to many prices, (depending on the quantity, a price is determined). I want to be able to edit these prices directly from my product controller, but I'm not really sure what the best practice to achieve this is.

I've tried using PartialViews but the databinding wouldn't work. Then I found http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/, which would be good to bulk edit the prices, but I don't know how to combine these with my parent (Product) model (using a viewmodel maybe)?

Could anyone link me to an up to date example of this? Since it's nothing really out of the ordinary what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe this might be relevant: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ but I still don't know what the best approach is to combine this with a model.

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct answer at the following URL: http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3